# How to protect unauthorised retrieve data from API in Android?

Tags: android, web-services, api, obfuscation, proguard

I am developing an Android app that consumes an API via a web service, sending a key to get information from the API, but if someone decompiles my application could use this key (which is a string) and extract all the information from the API. I have noticed that there are ways to obfuscate the code but there are also tools to de-obfuscate, so I wonder, what would be the best way to protect someone unauthorised retrieve data from the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never store keys in the code. This applies to code you write in any technology. Ideal way to do this is to get the key (token) from the server using some form of authentication and persist it locally in a secure way. Whenever you need this token, read it from this secure storage, and make the API calls. If the token expires, you do repeat this.

Good Luck

Comment: Yes - though this retains the possibility of a legitimate user completing the registration process with/for an imposter application.